# Visio Page ShapeSheet reference in shape shapesheet formula

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I'm trying to set the text field of a shape to the name of the layer it is on (Visio 2010).  I should be able to set the formula to this:

=ThePage!Layers.Name[LayerMember]

but that doesn't work because LayerMember is a string and a shape can be on multiple layers, i.e., LayerMember = "3" if it is only on the 3rd layer but can be "3;2;5" if it is on three different layers.  So, using LEFT(LayerMember, 1) gets the first value in the list but putting that in the index field of the above formula doesn't work either.  Putting a static value in the index field works just fine but I want to be able to change the layer of a shape and have the text on the shape change to the layer name.

Using LEFT(LayerMember,1) returns a string.  I can't find a way to convert the string value to a number to get the layer name value from the page's shapesheet.

I'm new at Visio but for some reason I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Layer is a property of shape, so try shpObj.Layer(1).Name this will give you the name of the first layer the shape is on. You will need to check shjObj.LayerCount to make sure that the shape actually is on a layer.

Comment: John - Thanks but that's not working for what I'm trying to do.  I'm just trying to enter a formula in the shape sheet of an object to set the value of a shape data field that I created.  I want the shape data's value to equal the name of the layer it is on but to get the name of the layer you have to access the background sheet's sheet data through ThePage!Layer.Name[Index value] - I'm trying to use the shape's layer member value as the above index value and I keep getting a formula error.

Comment: You can't set the shape's text via the shapesheet, so you'd be better off using VBA anyway.